# Transitive dependencies with different linkage to third-party libraries

Tags: cmake

I have a little bit of a convoluted question. I have a 3rd party dependency, which comes in static (`libthird.a`) and shared pic form (`libthird.so`).

I have a library, `util`, that depends on `libthird`.

And I have applications that depend on `util` that want to link `libthird` statically, and I have some shared libraries I need to produce that depend on `util` and need to link `libthird` dynamically.

My current (working) approach is something like the following:

```
add_library(third INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(third INTERFACE /path/to/libthird.a)
add_library(third_shared INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(third_shared INTERFACE /path/to/libthird.so)

add_library(util ${UTIL_SOURCES})
add_library(util_shared ${UTIL_SOURCES}) # same sources again!!
target_link_libraries(util PUBLIC third)
target_link_libraries(util_shared PUBLIC third_shared)

add_executable(some_app ...)
target_link_libraries(some_app PRIVATE util)

add_library(some_shared_object ...)
target_link_libraries(some_shared_object PUBLIC util_shared)
```

This works. But I'm building `util` (and, in reality, another half dozen libraries or so) twice... just to get different linker dependencies. Is there a saner way of doing this in cmake?

If I just `target_link_libraries()` on the top-level `some_app` and `some_shared_object`, I get the linker flags emitted in the wrong order, since `util` does depend on `third`.

Comment: Would it be feasible to make util_shared a thin wrapper around utill or are you really attached to a static util lib without -fPIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that you're taking is definitely one I've seen and also used myself before. It is fine if it is used for a small archive and/or one-off usage.

For the following examples, I assume a project structure like the following:

```
foo/
  CMakeLists.txt
  include/
    foo.h
  src/
    foo.c
```

So, I've also (naively?) used the following approach based on the knowledge that you can create (on Unix-based systems at least) a shared library from a static archive.

```
project(foo C)

set(SOURCES
  "src/foo.c")

set(LIBNAME "foo")

add_library(${LIBNAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${LIBNAME} PUBLIC "include")
target_compile_options(${LIBNAME} PUBLIC "-fPIC")

#

get_property(CUR_PREFIX TARGET ${LIBNAME} PROPERTY PREFIX)
get_property(CUR_SUFFIX TARGET ${LIBNAME} PROPERTY SUFFIX)
get_property(CUR_NAME TARGET ${LIBNAME} PROPERTY NAME)
get_property(CUR_OUTPUT_NAME TARGET ${LIBNAME} PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME)
get_property(CUR_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME TARGET ${LIBNAME} PROPERTY ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME)

message(STATUS "prefix: ${CUR_PREFIX}")
message(STATUS "suffix: ${CUR_SUFFIX}")
message(STATUS "name: ${CUR_NAME}")
message(STATUS "output name: ${CUR_OUTPUT_NAME}")
message(STATUS "archive name: ${CUR_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME}")

add_custom_command(TARGET ${LIBNAME} POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -shared -o libfoo.so -Wl,--whole-archive libfoo.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

My unresolved problem with this approach is that I haven't found a reliable and portable way to get the name of the static archive (`libfoo.a`). Hence, all those `message` commands for the [target properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-properties.7.html); they might behave differently on your platforms.

---

The most efficient way, that is also well-supported by `cmake`, is to use an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_library.html):

```
# cmake file

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(foo C)

set(SOURCES
  "src/foo.c")

set(LIBNAME "foo")
set(LIBNAME_OBJ "${LIBNAME}_obj")

add_library(${LIBNAME_OBJ} OBJECT ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${LIBNAME_OBJ} PUBLIC "include")
target_compile_options(${LIBNAME_OBJ} PUBLIC "-fPIC")

#

add_library(${LIBNAME} SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${LIBNAME_OBJ}>)
add_library(${LIBNAME}_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${LIBNAME_OBJ}>)
```

All examples were tested with cmake version 3.6.1.

Hope this helps. Let us know, if you've found a better way.